# Html code being removed when sending emails via mail PHP function

Tags: php, html, html-email

I am sending emails from my PHP script using the mail function.

Here is my whole script:

```
<?php

if (array_key_exists("email", $_POST)) {

    $to = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "My Subject";

    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <no-reply@myemail.com>' . "\r\n";

    $retval = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

     if( $retval == true ) {
        echo "Success";
     }else {
        echo "Failed";
     }

}
?>
```

This code is working fine it is that sometimes the html on my emails are being removed like below:

[image]
[image]

I am adding the html to an array and then parsing the array later but here is an example:

```
var rows = [];

rows.push("<tr><th style='background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;'>All Item Export</th></tr>");
rows.push("<tr><th style='background-color: #ededed; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;'></th><th style='background-color: #ededed; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;'></th></tr>");
rows.push("<tr><th style='background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;'>Item</th><th style='background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;'>Price</th></tr>");

for (var i = 0; i < checkedItemName.length; i++) { 

    var cleanedWord = removeWeirdCharacters(checkedItemName[i]);

    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        var myPush = "<tr><th style='background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;'>" + cleanedWord + "</th><th style='background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;'>" + checkedItemPrice[i] + "</th></tr>";
        rows.push(myPush);
    } else {
        var myPush = "<tr><th style='background-color: #ededed; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;'>" + cleanedWord + "</th><th style='background-color: #ededed; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;'>" + checkedItemPrice[i] + "</th></tr>";
        rows.push(myPush);
    }
}
```

So I guess my main question is, is the mail function known to remove html syntax, or do I have something wrong somewhere?

Note that it happens for different entries not the same one all the time.

Comment: are you asking for space to be removed?

Comment: is the actual content changed? have you checked? or is it how the email client is interpreting the HTML? does it happen with every email client?

Comment: try with `content-type` with T capital in it like `Content-Type:`

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['message'])` show? Is the space available there.
I cannot see the value of `checkedItemPrice`, does the space show up in there?